# Uncontrolled type exception 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' in System.Data.dll Index outside the limits of the matrix

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2014

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Coanc.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNYwd.png)

i take some screenshots of my program

public static PersonaComun CargarPersona(int ci, string consulta)
        {
            SqlConnection Conn = Conexion.ObtenerConexion();

```
        PersonaComun p1 = new PersonaComun();
        string sql = "Select * from persona,"+consulta+ ci;
        SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(sql, Conn);
        SqlDataReader x = comando.ExecuteReader();
        while (x.Read())
        {
            p1.Ci = x.GetInt32(0);
            p1.Nombre = x.GetString(1);
            p1.Ap = x.GetString(2);
            p1.Am = x.GetString(3);
            p1.Direccion = x.GetString(4);
            p1.Telefono = x.GetInt32(5);
            p1.Sexo = x.GetString(6);
            p1.Fechanac = x.GetDateTime(7);
            p1.Correo = x.GetString(8);
            p1.Idadmin = x.GetInt32(9);
            p1.Idboletero = x.GetInt32(9);
            p1.Idcliente = x.GetInt32(9);
            p1.Login = x.GetString(10);
            p1.Pwd = x.GetString(11);
            p1.Profesion = x.GetInt32(12);              
            p1.Turno = x.GetString(13);
            p1.Nit = x.GetInt32(14);
            p1.Puntos = x.GetInt32(15);

        }
        Conn.Close();
        return p1;

    }
```

Comment: What is the **exact** value of `sql` being executed`?

Comment: Please share the `CREATE TABLE` script for `persona`.